# VBA Userform won't work when called by macro

Tags: vba, excel, listbox, userform

I have a simple code that should call an Userform (CorrectiveActions) when the user inputs a value greater than 2.5 in certain cells.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal target As Range)
If target.Count > 1 Then Exit Sub
If Not Application.Intersect(target, Me.Range("F11:F1292,K11:K1292,P11:P1292")) Is Nothing Then
    If target >= 2.5 And IsNumeric(target) And Intersect(target, Me.Range("K11:K1292")) Is Nothing Or target.Offset(0, 1) >= 2.5 And Intersect(target, Me.Range("F11:F1292,P11:P1292")) Is Nothing Then CorrectiveActions.Show
End If
End Sub
```

The userform contains a listbox and I want to fill the cell below the one where the value greater than 2.5 is. I used the following code:

```
Private Sub ListBox1_Click()

Dim cellRow As Integer
Dim cellCol As Integer

cellRow = ActiveCell.Row
cellCol = ActiveCell.Column
Cells(cellRow, cellCol).Offset(1, 0).Value = ListBox1

End Sub
```

This Userform works fine when I launch it manually. However, when I input a value greater than 2.5 in the specified cell, the Userform shows up, but won't work. That is, the cell won't get filled.

Comment: `activecell.offset(1,0)` would suffice.

Comment: If you use `And` and `Or` in one `If` statement use brackets `()` to make clear which parts are `or` and which are `and`.

Comment: So you are changing something in the `Worksheet` from the code in `Worksheet_Change`. This changing then calls `Worksheet_Change` again, and again, and again... ;-). [Application.EnableEvents](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.application.enableevents) can avoid this.

Comment: I can't replicate this. Is the UserForm changing the worksheet?  If it is, you should probably disable events before showing it.